# Detect an identity PK of a table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

i created two tables in SQL Server :

```
create table Voyage(NumV int primary key identity, NbpAgadir int, NbpCasa int, NbpRabat int, Montant float)
create table Archive(NumV int foreign key references Voyage(NumV), NumPlace int, Ville varchar(10))
```

And I have a form in VS :

[image]

The second `DGV` contains only one row
I want when I press on `Valider Button` to save all data in the first row which is in the second `DGV` into `Voyage table`, so I wrote it's code and it works.

the problem is when I press on `Valider Button` it should also save the data in the first `DGV` into , but I don't know how to detect the PK of the new row who will be added to `Voyage table`, because I need when I save data into `Archive table` to write also the `NumV FK` which is a PK int the `Voyage table`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a stored procedure to save the record you can use @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY() in SQL to return the ID of the last record inserted.

See [this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) for info on usage.

Also see:

- [MSDN @@IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [MSDN SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259185%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not using a stored procedure, And I must use disconnected mode